# In a statistical model context, "overfitting" or "over fitting"?

Tags: word-usage, compounds, spacing, statistics

I have been writing a research proposal. In a particular part of the proposal, I talk about statistical methods that will be used to avoid "overfitting." This is a statistical concept describing a situation in which a model is overly complex and therefore has low error but not because of real signal but because of the large number of variables in the model. (See Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)

A friend commented that she thought it should be "over fitting". This is probably where the term "overfitting" came from.

I wanted to pose this question to the Stack Exchange English Language & Usage to get people's thoughts on the matter! Which spelling should it be, "over fitting" or "overfitting"?

Comment: Google Books shows a wider usage of "overfitting" vs "over fitting" in statistical/mathematical contexts: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=over+fitting%2Coverfitting&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cover%20fitting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coverfitting%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I have seen 'overfitting' a lot, 'over-fitting' also quite a bit, but 'over fitting' much less.

Comment: Please include the research you've done (on the accepted spelling variant/s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statistical context, you want to avoid *overfitting*. (I have not seen it written as *over fitting* in any of my graduate Economics or Statistics classes (graduated in Dec 2016). And a Google search for "over fitting" will direct you towards the more popular "overfitting.")

I searched for "overfitting" at scholar.google.com and found about 193,000 results. (One title is *Stopped training and other remedies for overfitting*).

Some have written it "over-fitting" (*On over-fitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation*).

One can also find "over fitting" (*Pseudomathematics and financial charlatanism: The effects of backtest over fitting on out-of-sample performance*).

[Overfitting](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2015/01/clever-methods-overfitting-avoid.html)

> is traditionally defined as training some flexible representation so that it memorizes the data but fails to predict well in the future.

I would suggest that you (tongue planted firmly in cheek):

1. Write "overfitting" for an academic context.
2. Draft it as "over fitting" when your girlfriend can see it.
3. Choose another term (e.g., "We sought a [parsimonious](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17570/2591) model.")
4. Seek appropriate relationship counseling.

Comment: Quite tongue in cheek, but thanks - very helpful!